# How send some info (values) in a link (<a>) to another page?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a page which generates a list of games and button for each game with value "BUY GAME". 
The objective is to execute multiple SQL queries when the button is clicked for a particular game.

What is an appropriate way of accessing the 'name','consolename',etc. for EACH game from the ARRAY and to execute queries on them in another page - purchase.php?

NOTE: I did consider using sessions but when I pass the variable $index as a SESSION variable, I only get the final value at all times.

buygame.php

```
<?php
session_start();
//connect to db
dbConnect("root", "") ;
dbSelect("webdesign");

//SEARCH FOR GAMES
print "<h3>Games to Buy: </h3>";
$query = "SELECT  gamecode,name, consolename,price, points, genre from game";
$result = runQuery($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
  $array[] = $row;
}
$index =0 ;

//DISPLAYING A LIST OF GAMES
 while($index<sizeof($array))
  { 
echo $array[$index]['name'];
echo $array[$index]['consolename'];
echo $array[$index]['genre'];
echo ("Price is: ".$array[$index]['price']." USD"); 
echo ("Loyalty Points: ".$array[$index]['points']);

//THE BUTTON "BUY GAME"
echo("<a href='purchase.php'><input type='submit' name='submit[$index]' value='Buy Game'/></a>");
$index = $index + 1;
}
?>
```

purchase.php

```
<?php
session_start();
//connect to database
dbConnect("root", "") ;
dbSelect("webdesign");
$index = 0;
echo "Button clicked ";

//I am trying this but I'm sure that this is not right
if (isset($_POST['submit[$index'])){
  print "$index was clicked";
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm guessing gamecode is unique here. So why don't you change your  href to `purchase.php?gamecode=$array[index]['gamecode']`?

Comment: Best way is using session . But the problem is you are not saving array to your session that's why you get only last(final) value every time. try to save $array in session which comes from  mysql_fetch_array($result). Then you are able to get all values on other pages too. And please use mysqli_* not mysql_*

Comment: Points noted! Yes, @Daan gamecode is unique and best choice for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `buygame.php` change the code to:

```
//THE BUTTON "BUY GAME"
echo("<a href='purchase.php?gamecode={$array[$index]['gamecode']}'><input type='submit' name='submit[$index]' value='Buy Game'/></a>");
```

In `purchase.php`

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['gamecode'])) {
  echo $_GET['gamecode'];
//and make ......
}
```

Comment: A complete answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
//THE BUTTON "BUY GAME"
$gamecode = $array[$index]['gamecode'];
echo("<a href='purchase.php?gamecode=$gamecode'><input type='submit' name='submit[$index]' value='Buy Game'/></a>");
$index = $index + 1;
```

Then in purchase.php You know exactly, what game has been bought.